# How to get the number of days between two dates ignoring some days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function, mysql-workbench

i need a function to do  something like this:

```
select datediff(  '2016-01-01', '2015-01-01')
```

but ignoring some days, example :

> calculate the interval between 2 dates only Mondays and Thursdays ignoring the other days

I do not want to make an select at the DB, only calculate the number of days between dates

sorry my English

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: he is not native english, so i think he couldnt express himself better, consider it

Comment: As @Siyual said this is not a code writing service, but to point you in the right direction. It is not usually difficult to take the number of days, divide by seven & mod by seven, then examine the days of the week the first & last days were (comparing to the remainder) to determine whether to add 1 to the quotient.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757919/count-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-mysql-only) deals with excluding weekends, so it should be a good reference for your purposes.

Comment: @PM77-1 - then there's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833261/mysql-week-calcualtion-between-two-dates - he can just multiply by 2.